# Error with graphpaper package from euclideangeometry package?

Tags: graphs, paper

I'm trying out the new (2020) graphpaper package by Claudio Beccari, and I get an error for the simplest possible document:

```
\documentclass{graphpaper}
\begin{document}
\bilinear
\end{document}
```

The error is caused by the package euclideangeometry, by the same author. The error seems to be inconsequential, because the graph paper is produced anyways as per the various commands, but it is a tad annoying nonetheless. Here is PDFLaTeX's output:

```
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/stefano"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode graphpaper-test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./graphpaper-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-07>
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphpaper/graphpaper.cl
s
Document Class: graphpaper 2020-10-10 1.0 A LaTeX class to generate several typ
es of graph papers
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
 (/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euclideangeometry/euclid
eangeometry.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/curve2e/curve2e.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cf
g)
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
)) (/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
 (/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg)
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-pdftex.def))
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse
.sty (/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdft
ex.def))
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse
-2020-10-01.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse
-generic.tex)))
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty))


! LaTeX Error: Command \PbDim already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 \newlength\PbDim
                     
) (/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
)
No file graphpaper-test.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mki
i
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-ba
se.sty
(/home/stefano/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys
.cfg)) [1] (./graphpaper-test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on graphpaper-test.pdf (1 page, 1405 bytes).
Transcript written on graphpaper-test.log.
*****
```

Comment: I reported this to the author

Comment: if you want an immediate local fix simply delete the line  `\newlength\PbDim` (line 29)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the `euclideangeometry` package by the same author, it loads the `curve2e` package and then both define the same length command.

Comment: Claudio has confirmed this is already fixed in the sources, he will make sure it is pushed to distributions soon.